# C++ reading data from a *.txt file to vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, ifstream, ofstream

I'm new one in C++ and have some misunderstandings about file read/write...

I have a .txt data file that contains information about the streets i.e. street, home number and number of flats

I have a task to read data from a file, add new one, delete unwanted and make some calculations about the number of flats on certain street

For data storage during the program work I made a vector of struct:

```
struct homeAdressBook {
    std::string street;
    char homeNumber[255];
    int flats;
};

std::vector<homeAdressBook> HAB;
```

Program code is below:

```
std::fstream document;
    document.open("name.txt");
    if (!document) {
        std::ofstream document;
        document.open("name.txt");
    }
    if (!document)
        std::cout << "File open error" << std::endl;
    else {
//Here (while loop) I want to read data from a file and add to my vector of struct for further usage, it partly works somehow but this point is unclear for me
        while (!document.eof()) {
            HAB.push_back(homeAdressBook());
            std::getline(document, HAB[i].street);
            document >> HAB[i].street;
            document >> HAB[i].homeNumber;
            document >> HAB[i].flats;
            i++;
        }
        document.close();
        do {
            switch (menu()) {
            case 0: {
                document.close();
                exit = false;
                break;
            }
//Here (case 1) I add new data and write it in file, here I have no problems at the moment
            case 1: {
                document.open("name.txt", std::ios::app);
                HAB.push_back(homeAdressBook());
                std::cin.ignore();
                std::cout << "Enter the address: ";
                std::getline(std::cin, HAB[i].street);
                std::cout << "Enter home number: ";
                std::cin.getline(HAB[i].homeNumber, 255);
                std::cout << "Enter number of flats: ";
                std::cin >> HAB[i].flats;
                document << HAB[i].street << HAB[i].homeNumber << HAB[i].flats << std::endl;
                document.close();
                i++;
                break;
            }
//Here (case 2) I want to read data from a file, it reads data except first line of data
            case 2: {
                int total = i;
                std::cout << std::setw(20) << "Street" << std::setw(20) << "Home Number" << std::setw(20) << "Number of flats" << std::endl;
                document.open("name.txt", std::ios::in);
                for (int j = 0; j < total; j++) {
                    std::cout << std::setw(20) << HAB[j].street << std::setw(20) << HAB[j].homeNumber << std::setw(20) << HAB[j].flats << std::endl;
                }
                document.close();
                break;
            }
//Here (case 3) data should be deleted from a file if necessary
            case 3: {
                document.open("name.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
                int strDelete = 0;
                std::cout << "0. Exit to main menu" << std::endl;
                for (i = 0; i < HAB.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << HAB[i].street << std::endl;
                }
                std::cout << "\nType number of street to delete: ";
                std::cin >> strDelete;
                if (strDelete)
                    i--;
                else break;
                HAB.erase(HAB.begin() + (strDelete - 1));
                document.close();
                break;
            }
            }
        } while (exit);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Data in .txt file is written like this:

```
aaa street 10 50
aaa street 10 45
bbb street 1 10
ccc street 1 12
ccc street 1/10 25
```

Each line in .txt file belongs to [i]-s vector of struct elements
I cannot understand how correctly add data from a .txt file to my vector of structs during the program work (name of the street can hold up to 5 or 6 words and how program can separate whether it is the name of the street or it is home number or number of flats)

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It was helpful and I already tried to do like this:

`unsigned int i = 0;
while (document >> HAB[i].street >> HAB[i].homeNumber >> HAB[i].flats) {
   HAB.push_back(homeAdressBook());
   i++;`

Program gives an error: Vector subscrip out of range

But if make another string object and keep there data during reading, than I need to work with that string but not with vector struct

Comment: Read into temporary variables and push back into the vector in the loop?

Comment: I just cannot understand the logic of how all this things happen

I have a file with data, with 'document >> HAB[i].street' I give the way where information will be stored, then I push back vector to go to another vector of struct element to store another sort of data there... where I'm wrong?

Comment: But when you do it like that, the very first iteration of the loop `HAB` will be *empty* and all indexing will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*. You could solve it by pushing back first outside the loop, but then at the end you will have one unused element in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you overload `operator>>` for your structure:

```
struct homeAdressBook
{
    std::string column1;
    std::string street;
    std::string homeAddress;
    int flats;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, homeAddressBook& address);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, homeAddressBook& address)
{
  input >> address.column1;
  input >> address.street;
  input >> address.homeAddress;
  input >> address.flats;
  return input;
}
```

The above will allow you to change your input process to:

```
std::vector<homeAddressBook> database;
homeAddressBook record;
//...
std::ifstream data_file("addresses.txt");
while (data_file >> record)
{
  database.push_back(record);
}
```

**Notes**

1. Your post describes 3 columns in the data, but your data source
   shows 4.
2. You open your `document` as an output stream (`ostream`) and you use
   `getline` on the output stream.
3. Your structure name has "book" which implies a *collection* of
   items.  I recommend using a name such as "Home_Address" to indicate
   a single item.  Use `std::vector` for the book.

**Edit 1:**
Prefixed members in `operator>>` with "address.".

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas! But where you declare operator overload i.e. 'input >> column1; input >> street ...' When I use it in my code IDE curses at me - column1, street, flat, homeNumber is undefined.. If I add like this: 'database[i].column1' it's not underlined with red line, but then I believe I need to declare 'int i = 0' and add 'for()' loop to increment 'i'... What about 'getline' in 'ostream' (your note #2) it gets the line from user and append it to my vector, is it wrong to do so?

Comment: You can find the declaration in the `struct`, the line above the terminating `}`.

Comment: I corrected the implementation of `operator>>`, see my latest edit.  BTW, you can find examples of this pattern by searching the internet for "c++ read file struct space separated".

Comment: I'm not using `std::getline` because it reads the entire record into a string.  Remember that `std::getline` is an **input** function and requires an **`std::istream`** derived object (e.g. the 'i' prefix is for input, such as `ifstream`).  The `std::getline` doesn't work with output streams (e.g. `ofstream`).  The `operator>>` for string will read characters until a whitespace is encountered.